# Display PHP Session Time Out With Javascript Time Counter

Tags: javascript, php, session, timeout, counter

I want to create a page that can display the php session using javascript, so when I reload the page again, the time fixed at run time and are not shown from the beginning again ...

I am looking for a script like that in forums or blogs but nothing that fits what I want. every time I reload the page again, the time is at the beginning again.

how do I make it? I ask for help at all .. I beg of you

Thanks.

Comment: You must try to write yourself first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of unclear what you're asking here. You might want to break it down some more and add some examples of what you're getting now and what you want differently. You can't get a PHP variable with Javascript -- it just doesn't work that way. The only way the two can interact is if PHP renders the variable into an HTML element that javascript picks up (after the page has loaded) or via AJAX with something like JSON. In the latter, you can tell Javascript to go run a PHP script, say to output the session in JSON, then return it to the page where Javascript can mess with it. Hope that helps.

Comment: i'm sorry my english is bad. yeah, maybe i have to put the variable into something (maybe div or directly print on javascript with echo) so javascript will load last time session. thanks for the help

Comment: If you are using jQuery, you can do this.

In PHP, echo '<span id="session">'.$session_var.'</span>;

Then, your script can var session = $("#session").html(); and you have your variable in javascript